# Laravel - Swagger - Error al lanzar una llamada api "Could not render n, see the console."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, api, laravel-6

he configurado un proyecto desde cero con laravel+passport y luego le he añadido swagger mediante el paquete "l5-swagger" : https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger
Mi stack es windows con php 7.2.30.

El fichero de rutas api.php lo tengo tal como este

```
Route::get('users','Api\v1\UserController@index');
```

Y el contenido del controlador anterior es este

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

/**
 * @OA\Info(title="API Usuarios", version="1.0")
 *
 * @OA\Server(url="http://api-cars.local/")
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/api/users",
     *     summary="Mostrar usuarios",
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="Mostrar todos los usuarios."
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response="default",
     *         description="Ha ocurrido un error."
     *     )
     * )
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

Ejecuto el comando >**php artisan l5-swagger:generate**

Y luego entro a la interficie de swagger para ejecutar el método y me da este error.
**Could not render n see the console**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto también **SwaggerUI**

```
<script src="{{ l5_swagger_asset('swagger-ui-bundle.js') }}"> </script>
<script src="{{ l5_swagger_asset('swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js') }}"> </script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',

    url: "{!! $urlToDocs !!}",
    operationsSorter: {!! isset($operationsSorter) ? '"' . $operationsSorter . '"' : 'null' !!},
    configUrl: {!! isset($configUrl) ? '"' . $configUrl . '"' : 'null' !!},
    validatorUrl: {!! isset($validatorUrl) ? '"' . $validatorUrl . '"' : 'null' !!},
    oauth2RedirectUrl: "{{ route('l5-swagger.oauth2_callback') }}",

    requestInterceptor: function() {
      this.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
      return this;
    },

    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],

    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],

    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })

  window.ui = ui
}
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes revisar y compartir la configuracion de Swagger UI `SwaggerUI({ .. })` al parecer hay algun problema con la definicion de `requestInterceptor`

Comment: Gracias @F.Igor, adjunto el código de SwaggerUI en el post principal.

Comment: @F.Igor he probado a bajar este proyecto y me da el mismo error

https://github.com/LaravelDaily/Laravel-OpenAPI-Swagger-Documentation-Example

Comment: El problema debe estar en la linea `this.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{ csrf_token() }}';` intenta comentarla con `//` y ver si sale otro error distinto. Al parecer `this.headers` no esta definido (nulo)

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la version del SwaggerUIBundle puede que la forma de definir el requestInterceptor es otra, como se define en la documentacion

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#network

```
requestInterceptor: function(request) {
  request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
  return request;
},
```

Si en este caso la implementacion de la API no exige un CSRF Token personalizado en el header, puede que no sea necesario definir `requestInterceptor` y puedes probar removiendo esta definicion.